# Change size of Windows 7 Explorer most recently used searches list

Tags: windows-explorer, search

Is it possible to increase the size of Windows 7 search MRU list?
Below is URL to screenshot which describes what I'm saying about.

[image: Search List]

The default 3 items in list is not always convenient. I know about 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\WordWheelQuery' key and MRUListEx value but it is the place where search list is stored which is not what I'm actually looking for.